# OpCache caching env.php configuration file in Magneto 2.2.4

Tags: caching, magento2, opcache

I have updated to **Magento 2.2.4** recently and thought my cache wasn't working. It turns out that updating `env.php` or modifying via **CLI** just updated `env.php` file however previous configurations have been cached somewhere within **opcache** and changes are not reflected until invalidating the whole opcache. I am wondering if anyone else has experienced this / knows a fix for this happening?

When modifying via admin the configurations seem to be applied however so this method seems to do something differently.

Comment: I added the env.php to opcache blacklist in the end seemed to do the trick.